# Python can't find self-written module

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I'm writing a python module and want to install it. The structure is as follows:

```
look-up
├── look-up
│   ├── utilities
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── validator.py
│   └──  __init__.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── MANIFEST.in
```

setup.py looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from codecs import open
from os import path

here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))

with open(path.join(here, 'README.md'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(
      name = 'look_up',
      version = '0.0.1',
      packages = find_packages(),        
      )
```

Afte i run:

```
python setup.py develop
```

and try to import it it I get the error:

```
No module named 'look_up'
```

Can someone help me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your directory structure uses the name `look-up`. But that is not a valid Python identifier: you can't do `import look-up`. It appears that `setup` has coerced this name to `look_up`. But that doesn't fix the folder names. I would start by fixing that.

Comment: I've simplified the above script a bit so I miswrote. in setup.py I actually use the name look_up. But could the folder names be an issue?

Comment: if the folder is called `look-up` then yes it will be an issue as it doesn't match the name its looking for

Comment: Thank you, It's working!